# Using BASH versus ASH on Synology

Tags: scripting, regular-expression, ash

The majority of my photo files have the following naming convention / format `IMG_20131204_120000.JPG`, showing date and time the photo was taken (iPhone/Apple naming convention). However, not all my photos follow this naming convention. With the help of this forum we evolved the script as follows:

```
for x in *.JPG *.jpg *.TIF *.tif *.PNG *.png *.BMP *.bmp *.GIF *.gif *.IMG *.img *.JPEG *.jpeg *.TIFF *.tiff; do
  d=$(date -r "$x" +%Y%m%d)" - Family Photos"
  if [[ "$x" =~ ^[iI][mM][gG][_-][1-2][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][_-][0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9][.][a-zA-Z]*$ ]]; then
    d=$(expr substr "$x" 5 8)" - Family Photos"
  fi
  mkdir -p "$d" >/dev/null 2>&1
  mv -- "$x" "$d/" >/dev/null 2>&1
done
rmdir ' - Family Photos' >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I use the `if` statement to take the date from the File name itself if the filename is in the format `IMG_20131204_120000.JPG` as this date most accurately reflects the date the photo was actually taken, but if the file doesn't follow this naming convention I take the operating system date of when the file was last modified/created.

I plan to run this script every night to categorize the photos uploaded during the previous 24 hours.  My problem is I now find out that my Synology system only supports ASH not BASH shell and therefore the regular expression `=~` in the `if` statement doesn't work.  I can use IPKG to install a BASH package.  Is there an easy way to have just this script use BASH while the rest of the system is untouched and uses ASH?  Or alternatively is there a way to do the same thing in the `if` statement using the ASH shell?

Comment: Photo image files often contain EXIF data with the exact date/time, that don't change if the filename changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ash doesn't have regular expressions, but it has shell wildcard matching. You need to use `case`, wildcard matching isn't available via `test` a.k.a. `[ … ]`.

There is no way to express the regex `[a-zA-Z]*` using wildcards, but you can perform the same test in two steps, one for the first part and one for the second part.

```
case "$x" in
  [iI][mM][gG][-_][1-2][09][0-9][0-9][0-1][0-9][0-3][0-9][_-][0-2][0-9][0-6][0-9][0-6][0-9][.]*)
    case "${x#*.}" in
      *[!a-zA-z]*) :;;
      *) d=${x#*[-_]}; d="${d%%[-_]*} - Family Photos";;
    esac
esac
```

The prefix and suffix stripping constructs are portable to all POSIX shells, you don't need to use `expr`.

Comment: Finally got around to implementing this after researching exactly how the script works. I learned a lot thank you. Works perfect. Genious.